# CURL returns bool(false). Why?

Tags: php, curl

I want to parse data from the site https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/check/driver.

I do it like this:

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
    $cookieFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'ccf');
    $timeOut = ini_get('max_execution_time') - 5;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        [
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeOut,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeOut,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookieFile,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookieFile,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
                "num" => "7746468933",
                "date" => "2010-16-20",
                "captchaWord" => "",
                "reCaptchaToken" => "03........FU"
            ],
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://check.gibdd.ru/proxy/check/driver/',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
            'Pragma: no-cache',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Origin: http://check.gibdd.ru/',
            'Referer: http://check.gibdd.ru/check/driver',
            ],
        ]
    );
    
    var_dump(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
```

As a result, I get bool (false) Failed to connect to xn - b1afk4ade.xn - 90adear.xn - p1ai port 443: The connection timed out strangely, but why doesn't it connect? from the browser of norms .. should get error 201 on the idea that the captcha did not work. And I get false. Please tell me. Thank you in advance.

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, - Doesn't help.

Comment: I am doing a car inspection service for people. I do not steal information, do not copy, do not harm anyone.

Comment: Why don't you use [php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) for this ?

Comment: As @mario basically said, whenever you are having problems integrating with a service, it is best to contact that service directly to see what they recommend. For instance, they put a CAPTCHA on for what is probably a legitimate reason (probably to stop people from automatically using their site as you are doing). If you feel that your case should be allowed, just contact the site's author and if they agree with you, they'll probably remove the CAPTCHA completely for you, and possibly give you an API so you don't need to jump through these hoops in the first place.